Soap API Post Action getting 200 status but not creating the record
I tried to create a record by using a SOAP API through Postman, C# code, Power Automate. I am getting the success status code 200, but the record is not created. When I try from the Widzler extension in the Chrome, it is creating the record. Can any one give a solution to fix it?
I tried with Postman and C# code, but I'm unable to find the issue. I need to create the record through Postman, C# code. etc.
Here I attached sample code:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
      string order = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
          "<Body><Create xmlns=\"urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customer_card_excel\">" +
          "<Customer_Card_Excel><Key></Key><No>2233</No><Name>CRM POC23</Name>" +
          "<!-- Optional --><AgedAccReceivableChart><Aged_Acc_Receivable_Chart><Key></Key></Aged_Acc_Receivable_Chart>" +
          "</AgedAccReceivableChart></Customer_Card_Excel></Create> </Body></Envelope>";
    
      XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    
      xDoc.LoadXml(order);
     
    //  string url = "http://ab-bc-qa.in.abc.net:1234/QA_WEB/WS/abcPrivate%20Limited/Page/Customer_Card_Excel";
      string username = "xyz@zbc.com";
          string password = "xyz12";
      var response1 = string.Empty;
      // Create HttpClient with credentials
      HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
          {
              Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
              PreAuthenticate = true
          };
    
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
          {
              BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
          };
    
          // Set the Accept header to JSON
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     
      
      string strCustomerdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerdata);
      //HttpContent c = new StringContent(strCustomerdata, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      HttpContent c = new StringContent(xDoc.InnerXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
      Uri u = new Uri(url);
      using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
      {
          HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
          {
              Method = HttpMethod.Post,
              RequestUri = u,
              Content = c
          };
    
          HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(u, c);
          if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              response1 = result.StatusCode.ToString();
              Console.WriteLine("data inserted");
          }
      }
}


Show us your code.
